# System with half GUI

Tags: gui, debian

I have unusual question, hope it's ok to ask in ubuntu forum, if not, delete please

I was thinking about simple (for me) system based on linux, where will be instead of desktop image or icons, only black linux command line to start apps (and work with as command line), and when the apps are running, then switch between them with Alt+Tab. 
Is there anything like that?[image]

other words it should contain only some window manager and command line. Is it possible? Does anything similar exist or can I simply (very simply?? :) ) make something like e.g. from Arch linux or from Debian? How?

Thank you :)

Comment: I believe your question would be much more suited for the ubuntuforums.org (perhaps under 'Desktop Environments').

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look into Tiling window managers, [Awesome WM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) seems to fit the needs you want.

Comment: This looks nice, but Im total newbie to GUIs and I cant manage to set it. I'm trying on debian 7.7 wheezy (as shown by lsb_relase -a) in Virtualbox. Can you show me the way to get it?